# Mysql - Condition between rows

Tags: mysql

i looked all over the threads but i couldn't find anything to answer my question (or i havent search with the proper question :P ) i am self learning mysql and now i am stuck at this and couldnt find any solution.

So my question is, if is possible to select rows from a table between 2 dates and only those where the difference between rows is for example 6 months and if not show how much time has passed.

Table:

```
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |  name  |    action    |    date    |
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
| 1  | name 1 |   exchange   | 2011-06-15 |
| 2  | name 1 |   exchange   | 2011-12-15 |
| 3  | name 1 |   exchange   | 2012-06-15 |
| 4  | name 1 |   exchange   | 2013-01-15 | -1 month
| 5  | name 2 |   exchange   | 2014-01-15 |
| 6  | name 2 | intervention | 2014-05-15 |
| 7  | name 2 |   exchange   | 2014-06-15 |
| 8  | name 2 |   exchange   | 2015-05-15 | - 11 months
+----+--------+--------------+------------+
```

so where i stuck is

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select * from table
        WHERE intervention like '%exchange%'
        AND date between '2011-01-15' and NOW() )
WHERE ....
 - if difference between row 1 and row 2, row 2 and row 3 till no rows? else write difference ?
```

But from my guess i have to make 2 selects and after that join them or something similar, 1 select that will take all the "general" rows and one with the condition in between the results i just dont know how exactly i am supposed to do this or if is possible with sql only.

Do you guys have a solution for this? if you do can you explain what you did? :D

Desired output:

```
+--------+--------------+------------+
|  name  |    action    |    date    |
+--------+--------------+------------+
| name 1 |   exchange   | 2011-06-15 |
| name 1 |   exchange   | 2011-12-15 |
| name 1 | OK exchange  | 2011-12-15 | - generated because row 1 and 2 meet the requirements
| name 1 |   exchange   | 2012-06-15 |
| name 1 | OK exchange  | 2012-06-15 | - generated because row 2 and 3 meet the requirements
| name 1 |   exchange   | 2013-01-15 | 
| name 1 | 1 month late | 2013-12-15 | - generated because row 3 and 4 DONT meet the requirements
```

Thank you in advance.
with respect, iaiu

Comment: Kindly show to us your desired output,

Comment: i hope i did it the right way, i am new on posting threads here i generally just read them didnt made an account till now :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want a result with both source and processed data mixed, which is a bit... unorthodox. Let's have try from the start. First we join the table with itself, giving them two nicknames. Note that t2 pairs every next row to t1:

```
select t1.name as name, t1.date as date, datediff(t2.date, t1.date) as diff_in_days
from table t1, table t2
where
  t1.action like '%exchange%' and
  t1.date between '2011-01-15' and NOW() and
  t1.name = t2.name and
  t1.id = t2.id-1
order by t1.name, t1.date;
```

We have got the pairs with time difference between them, but in days. The definition of "6 months" is up to you, let's now assume it's 182 days. Now let's wrap the above in your business logic:

```
select
  name,
  date,
  if(diff_in_days <=182, "OK", concat(diff_in_days - 182, "days late")) as message
from (
select t1.name as name, t1.date as date, datediff(t2.date, t1.date) as diff_in_days
from table t1, table t2
where
  t1.action like '%exchange%' and
  t1.date between '2011-01-15' and NOW() and
  t1.name = t2.name and
  t1.id = t2.id-1
) res
order by res.name, res.date;
```

Now, if you need the original data as well, use the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and put both the above and original tables' rows next to each other.

Comment: thank you for your response and explanations, i generally process data with php but somehow i wondered if i could do this directly from sql. i will check this adapt it to my needs and come back with a result. thank you again